# Casting `const std::pair<K, V>*` to `const std::pair<const K, V>*`

Tags: c++

The question is whether the following is undefined behaviour (and if not, what guarantees do I have):

```
    using kv = std::pair<std::string, int>;
    using ckv = std::pair<const std::string, int>;
    kv x = {"239", 239};
    const kv* p = &x;
    std::cout << p->first << " " << p->second << "\n";
    // Dangerous cast
    const ckv* cp = static_cast<const ckv*>(static_cast<const void*>(p));
    std::cout << cp->first << " " << cp->second << "\n";
```

I know that `kv` and `ckv` are two different types and hence pointers are incompatible, but perhaps I am wrong? The snippet above compiles on my machine and does the expected thing - is it just a "happy coincidence" due to two types having similar layout that hides undefined behaviour or is it something I can depend on reliably?

Comment: const and non-const nested types have always same layout. If there are no special specializations of templates for const types. And pair shoudn't have any different handling of const and non-const.

Comment: I'd change the dangerous cast from `const ckv* cp = static_cast<const ckv*>(static_cast<const void*>(p));` to `const ckv* cp = reinterpret_cast<const ckv*>(p);`.  Unless I'm mistaken (and I may be, I'm not a *language lawyer* anymore), this is a case of "I (the developer) have insider information unavailable to the compiler that makes this seemingly dangerous cast perfectly copacetic."

Comment: @Eljay The two lines are exactly equivalent here. It is how `reinterpret_cast` between pointer types is defined.

Comment: @user17732522 • True, and a C style cast would be exactly equivalent as well.